# How to tell whether put or call is more expensive using put-call parity?

Tags: finance

Using the following example can someone explain to me why the put is more expensive in part a and why the call is more expensive in part b?

$$C_E-P_E=S(0)-X \cdot \frac{1}{1+R}$$
where $X$ is the strike price.

Assume that the stock price is governed by a binomial model. The initial price of the stock is $S(0)=100$. The return on a risk-less security over one period of time is $R=10\%$. The parameters $u$ and $d$ are not known.
a. Which of the following two options is more expensive: A European put option with strike $120$ and expiration $1$ or a European call option with strike $120$ and expiration $1$?

b. Which of the following two options is more expensive: A European put option with strike $110$ and expiration $2$ or a European call option with strike $120$ and expiration $2$?

for part a I get $C_E-P_E=100-120 \cdot \frac{1}{1+0.1}$
and I know $100-120 \cdot \frac{1}{1+0.1} \lt 0$
but why does this mean the put is more expensive?

Comment: For b.  the forward price is $120$ so the put is well out of the money, whereas the call is at-the-money.  Parity tells us that the $120$ call has the same price as the $120$ put and the $120$ put is more valuable than the $110$ put.

Comment: thank you, I also realized the reason behind why the put is more expensive in part a.